# iPhone - Drawing 2D Shapes

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, core-graphics

I have an array of 2D points which make an irregular polygon.
What I want to do is draw the borders of it and then fill it with a color.

I am using Cocos2d to code the game around, but I have not found a fill function in Cocos2d, only the

```
ccDrawLine
```

and such.

Is there a simple way to draw filled shapes in Cocos2?

I have also noted that Core Graphics would work beautifully for this purpose, but I am not able to integrate it with Cocos2d. I put this in to the draw function of my CCLayer:

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextClearRect(ctx, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]);
```

And every time I run it i get this error:

```
<Error>: CGContextClearRect: invalid context
```

Answer (score 0):

Cocos2D is ultimately OpenGL so a possibility would be to add the functionality you are looking for manually.  Perhaps add a `ccDrawPoly` function with parameters to determine whether it should be filled or not.  You should be able to find a great deal of documentation on doing polygon fills in OpenGL.